# Undefined reference to 'yylex()'

Tags: g++, bison, lex, undefined-reference, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use flex and bison to create a simple scripting language. Right now, I'm just trying to get a calculator working.

I can't get it to compile, though. When I run this makefile:

```
OBJECTS = hug.tab.o hug.yy.o
PROGRAM = hug.exe

CPP = g++
LEX = flex
YACC = bison

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJECTS)
$(CPP) $^ -o $(PROGRAM)

clean:
$(RM) *.o *.output *.tab.* *.yy.* $(PROGRAM)

%.tab.o: %.tab.cpp
$(CPP) -c -o $@ $<

%.tab.cpp: %.ypp
$(YACC) -vd $<

%.yy.o: %.yy.c
$(CPP) -c -o $@ $<

%.yy.c: %.l
$(LEX) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cpp
$(CPP) -c -o $@ $<
```

on my .l and .ypp files, I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `yylex()'
```

And if I make the command for `all` like this:

```
$(CPP) $^ -o $(PROGRAM) -lfl
```

it says it couldn't find `-lfl`. And if I make it like this:

```
$(CPP) $^ -o -lfl $(PROGRAM)
```

it goes back to the `undefined reference` error.

Sorry I'm kind of clueless about this.

EDIT: I have flex installed. I tried changing it from -lfl to C:/GnuWin32/lib/libfl.a (I'm trying to use Windows because Linux has odd problems on my computers and I don't have a Mac yet), but it still has the same error.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the C/C++ compiler that you're using. "-o" is an option that produces an output file; the very next argument must specify the name of that file. "-l" specifies a library; the documentation will tell you the naming convention and location where the compiler will look for this library. As a guess, you haven't installed the flex library.

Comment: i am getting same problem. My program is compiling with gcc, problem with g++ version.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you're compiling hug.yy.c with g++ (treating it as C++) instead of gcc.  This is the file that defines `yylex`, so by compiling it as C++ you end up with a C++ yylex function while the other files are looking for a C yylex function.

Try sticking `extern "C" int yylex();` into the first section of your hug.l file so that it will use C linkage for yylex instead of C++

Answer (score 7):

Basically, do either of the following:

1. Adding `%option noyywrap` in the flex file and removing the `-lfl` part in the command would be OK.
2. `#define` `yylex` as `extern "C"` works too. Since, it prevents C++ mixing up with the name.
3. Install flex-old rather than flex. flex-old bydefault solves the problem like solution 2 so u dont have to bother about it.

Comment: Can you summarize the solution in your answer? It would be helpful in case the link is no longer valid.

Comment: My bad :' . Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `%option noyywrap` in .l file and removing the `-lfl` option works for me.

**flex 2.6.4**

**bison 3.8.2**

Answer (score 1):

have you installed the flex library ? if yes, try something like

```
$(CPP) $^ /path/of/flex/lib/libfl.a -o $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: I have it installed. I tried changing it from -lfl to C:/GnuWin32/lib/libfl.a (I'm trying to use Windows because Linux has odd problems on my computers and I don't have a Mac yet), but it still has the same error.