# undefined reference to 'yylex' - compiled by g++

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make a lexical analyzer using flex. For convenience, I want to compile my `scanner.l` to `lex.yy.cc`, and then compile the `.cc` file by command:
`g++ lex.yy.cc -lfl`.

The `-lfl` is required. The g++ then gave me following error message: undefined reference to 'yylex'
Here is the briefly snapshot of my `scanner.l`

```
%{
...
#include ...
extern "C" int yylex();
...
%}
...
%option c++
%option noyywrap

%%
/* rules */
%%
```

I have done some study, [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424044/17293399) says it should be fixed by adding `extern "C" int yylex();`. However, it did not.

I am using `flex 2.6.4` on a remote(from school) linux machine.
[image]

Comment: You also need a definition of `yylex`. Right now, you only have a declaration.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `lex.yy.c` to see if `yylex` has been generated?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I thought `flex` should do the definition for me.

Comment: @john No, there is not. Shouldn't the `flex` help me generate the `yylex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: remove `%option c++`.**

---

> The `-lfl` is required.

Are you sure? libfl provides only two functions: `yywrap()`, which you do not need because of

> ```
> %option noyywrap
> ```

, and `main()`, which you do not need if you provide your own `main()`.  The `main()` in libfl just calls `yylex()` over and over until the latter signals end-of-input, which is surely where the depency on `yylex()` is coming from in your case.

If you have some external requirement to rely on libfl for your program's `main`, then you have shot yourself in the foot by specifying

> ```
> %option c++
> ```

.  That option is more about [the API the generated scanner will provide](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx) than about the language that will be used to compile it.  You do need to compile as C++ if you use it, but you *can* still compile as C++ if you don't.  You should omit that option to have `yylex()` as the scanner entry point.

Declaring C linkage for `yylex()` is what you do if you plan to **omit `%option c++`**, compile with a C++ compiler, and link with other code (such as libfl) that expects the C interface for `yylex()`.  But it is rare for that to be an advantageous combination, because the kinds of actions a typical scanner wants to perform don't gain much from C++ relative to C.  Thus, if you want the C interface to `yylex()` then it is usually cleaner to just write the actions in C and compile the scanner with a C compiler.  And of course, you can still call that from C++ if you like.

Comment: To clarify, what I meant ***required*** is that it is required by TA.

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed. `lex,yy.c` is now compiled by `g++` perfectly.